Customize settings for dependencies declared using Gradle gitRepository
I have the following declaration in settings.gradle:
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(new URI("https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-android.git")) {
        producesModule("com.wireguard.android:tunnel")
    }
}

Unfortunately, the repo does not publish releases, so I need Gradle to checkout and build from scratch:
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.wireguard) {
        version {
            branch = "master"
        }
    }
}

I'm getting: 'SDK is not defined' and 'NDK is not defined' when trying to sync the project, which I'm assuming is because my local.properties containing:
sdk.dir=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk

is not getting applied.
What is the best solution for Gradle to pick up my settings from local.gradle, when building the dependency?
I know there's a plugins {} closure available inside gitRepository(), so perhaps I could use the copy plugin? I'm not quite sure where to tell it to copy local.properties to, though - is there a way to get the path under which Gradle will check out the repository for building?
Or perhaps there is a simpler way to make sure sdk.dir and ndk.dir are defined, when building the module from Git?

Your best bet is to use Jitpack.
In your root build.gradle file add jitpack as a source:
google()
mavenCentral()

maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

and then in your app build.gradle add the depdendency:
    dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.WireGuard:wireguard-android:1.0.20231018'
    }

note that builds seem to be failing for the most recent tags, so you may have to experiment to find a working release.
See: https://www.jitpack.io/#WireGuard/wireguard-android/1.0.20230706
